# Не работает цвет текста в консольной программе на c++ (MSYS mingw64)

Tags: c++, g++, mingw-w64, msys2

Ранее задавал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454543/%d0%9b%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b7-stdgetline) и мне посоветовали перейти с cygwin на MSYS2.

Поставил MSYS2 всё заработало как надо, но у меня теперь не работают цвета для текста в моей программе. Цвета делал по [этой статье](https://habr.com/ru/company/macloud/blog/558316/)

Когда в программе пишу

`std::cout << "\033[3;36;44m" << "TEXT";`

В результате в консоли выводится обычным цветом

`←[3;36;44mTEXT`

Подскажите как исправить?

Компилировал

```
MINGW64 ~
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-12.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --buil
d=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-head
er-dir=/mingw64/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --wit
h-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable
-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-d
ynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --ena
ble-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls -
-disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr
=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project' -
-with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-li
bstdcxx-debug --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 12.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

Comment: Таак. А из какого терминала вы запускаете программу? Из cmd? Из msys-овского mintty? Вообще, на винде традиционно цвет текста задается вызовами winapi, но возможно ansi-последовательности тоже можно как-то заставить работать.

Comment: В Windows ANSI-последовательности уже давно не работают :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , через msys-овский работает, а через cmd не пашет.

Comment: Если вам нужен емулятор VT100, то и используйте его. Программа CMD не является таким эмулятором.

Comment: Ну вот. Если хотите поддержать CMD, дергайте WinAPI. Еще появился какой-то новый Windows Terminal, в котором тоже должны работать ansi-последовательности.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1454833/312941