# Есть ли какая-нибудь очень простая кросс-платформенная C++ header-only библиотека для изменения цвета текста в консоли?

Tags: c++, текст, поиск-библиотек, цвета

Ищу очень простую кросс-платформенную C++ header-only библиотеку для изменения цвета текста в консоли.

Дело в том что [управляющие последовательности](https://habr.com/ru/company/macloud/blog/558316/) для Windows не работают.

Comment: ¿Если вы начали использовать управляющие последовательности VT100, то может было бы проще включить их обработку в CMD при необходимости?

Comment: @user7860670 а как это сделать кроссплатформенно и чтобы пользователю программы не нужно было этим заниматься?

Comment: По идее есть флаг ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING который переключает режим эмуляции VT100

Comment: @user7860670 ...и который в куче случаев не срабатывает. Он работает в режиме "новой консоли", но в нем не работают нормально некоторые консольные программы (например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/866479/195342); приходится переходить в режим "старой консоли", а там не работает `ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`...

Comment: @Harry Так и путь эти некоторые консольные программы не работают, главное, чтобы заработала эта.

Comment: @user7860670 Это уж кому как... Предпочитаю FTE, жалко, что его забросили...

Comment: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING кажется платформозависимый

Comment: Естественно, это же WinAPI

Comment: https://fmt.dev/latest/api.html#color-api

Comment: @tocic А оно умеет дергать winapi? Или просто красивый способ формировать ansi-последовательности?

Comment: @Антон Завернуть единственный платформозависимый вызов в `#ifdef _WIN32` - не худший вариант.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не умеет, посмотрел [сорс](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/master/include/fmt/color.h).

Comment: Тогда попробуйте первую выдачу в поисковике https://github.com/aafulei/color-console/.

Comment: @tocic А это поделие работает только на винде.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat через `#ifdef`, как вы указали. Вот тут утверждают, что кроссплатформенно https://github.com/pniedzielski/term-colors.

Comment: Попробуйте это:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16431/%D0%A6%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8